# Show that the product $\sigma $-algebra is generated by the $\pi $-system $\{B _1 \times B _2 : B \in \Sigma _1 , B _2 \in \Sigma _2 \} $

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Show that the product $\sigma $-algebra is generated by the $\pi $-system $\{B _1 \times B _2 : B_1 \in \Sigma _1 , B _2 \in \Sigma _2 \} $

Let $(X , \Sigma _1) $ and $(Y , \Sigma _2 ) $ be two measure spaces

Let $\Sigma = \Sigma _1 \times \Sigma _2$ be the $\sigma $-algebra generated by the two projective mappings $\rho _1(x,y)=x $, $\rho _2 (x,y)=y $,
ie $\Sigma =\sigma ( \rho _1, \rho _2 ) $

Define $\mathcal I = \{B _1 \times B _2 : B_1 \in \Sigma _1 , B _2 \in \Sigma _2 \} $

**Show that $\sigma ( \mathcal I )=\Sigma $**

---

Since $B _1 \times B _2 = \rho_1 ^{-1 } (B _1 ) \cap \rho_2 ^{-1 } (B _2 ) $

$\sigma ( \mathcal I )\subset \Sigma $

**How can I show the converse?**

Comment: I am more than certain that this came up before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X\times Y$ is equipped with $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma\left(\mathcal{I}\right)$
then the projections $\rho_{1},\rho_{2}$ are both measurable.

This
follows directly from $\rho_{1}^{-1}\left(B_{1}\right)=B_{1}\times Y\in\mathcal{I}\subseteq\sigma\left(\mathcal{I}\right)$
for $B_{1}\in\Sigma_{1}$ and $\rho_{2}^{-1}\left(B_{2}\right)=X\times B_{2}\in\mathcal{I}\subseteq\sigma\left(\mathcal{I}\right)$
for $B_{2}\in\Sigma_{2}$.

This allows the conclusion that $\Sigma=\sigma\left(\rho_{1},\rho_{2}\right)\subseteq\sigma\left(\mathcal{I}\right)$.

Note that $\sigma\left(\rho_{1},\rho_{2}\right)$ is actually defined as the 'smallest' $\sigma$-algebra s.t. the projections are both measurable.